# How to make Tomcat Webapp not only accessible on port 8080 but also on port 80

Tags: linux, centos, tomcat, port, linux-vserver

I'm currently trying to set up my first V-Server (CentOS 7) with Tomcat to run a Web-App.

Everything works fine now, but I am facing one last problem that stops me from releasing it:

I can only access my Tomcat WebApp via `exampledomain.com:8080/WebAppName/` but I would love it to just be `exampledomain.com/WebAppName/`.

After hours (literally like 20) I haven't come up with a solution, but having the user to always type `8080` is not an option for me.

I would be extremely happy if somebody had a solution or tip for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a reverse proxy in front of your Tomcat. And you should either alter Tomcat to only listen in 127.0.0.1 or shut access on port 8080 in the firewall.

Two examples of software you can use are Apache and nginx. With Apache you would use ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse as such:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

With nginx it would be

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For completeness' sake, on most systems you can run Tomcat directly on port `80` (as an almost **unpriviledged** user). The only privilege it requires is the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` [capability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

This can be accomplished twofold:

1. [This requires **SystemD** v229 or later, so it [excludes Centos 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/550631/381289)] By asking **SystemD** to run Tomcat with this capability:

   ```
   systemctl edit --full tomcat.service
   ```

and add:

```
    AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
```

to the `[Service]` section.

2. By running Tomcat through **authbind** (cf. [this blog post](https://webhosting.net/how-to-get-tomcat-running-on-centos-7-2-using-privileged-ports-1024/)), which allows a further restriction of the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability: e.g. you may configure Tomcat to be able to bind port `80` only.